# UIImageView will not resized to cell size with constrains

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am completely lost from this auto-layout .
I need to set a collection view in screen size, a cell in screen width, and dynamic height .

I have a `UICollectionView` in the size of a screen .
I have a cell created in `storyboard`. The height of the cell is dynamic hight changed during run with :

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The cell has trailing and leading space to its super view(collection view) constrains , and i get its size as expected- in the screen width (although maybe i do something wrong ) .

Inside that cell there is a `UIImageView`(with `clipped subviews` checked) . what i want to do is to set the width of this image view to the width of the cell, and its height to be dynamic.

So, i set image height constrain outlet which i change during code. it works great. 
The image view has ***pinned to the cell from top, left and right .***

What actually happens, is that in simulator everything is in place and works good .
In device, the image view is *smaller than the cell size* (cell is in the right size-screen size), so the image view starts from (0,0) as expected, has the right height , but the width- is not in the size of the cell, but smaller . (2/3) .

**EDIT:**
WOW !  I found something very surprising . if i remove from the image view the trailing space to cell- it than works on device and not on simulator. If i add it back, it works on simulator and not on device .
WAHT IS THAT ??

What am i missing here ?

Comment: I really wonder what is so bad about this question , but i worked hard and found solution. hope other people will learn from it, and that the down voter will have good life, and love himself.

Answer (score 0):

My only solution was to set a constrain for the width of the image view, and set its outlet and change it during run time .

I still dont know why when cell change its size, image view that aligned to it is not changed also.
I have an idea, that it works in simulator but not on device because in simulator the cell size is known before run time , and on device its not.

Hence, set constrain width/height for every dynamic view that you have . It solves many problem, and gives you freedom .